# Call is-valid when pagination is applied to data in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I have a `ModelViewSet` and I am using `ModelSerializer`. I am also using `Pagination` that is from `django.core`.

My views code snippet that works:

```
page_number = request.data.get("page")
data = Model.objects.filter()
paginator = Paginator(data, 100)
page = paginator.page(int(page_number))
serializer = self.serializer_class(page, many=True)
list_data = serializer.data
```

What I want to do is to `validate` the data. Meaning to do:

```
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    list_data = serializer.validated_data
```

But I am getting error if I try to run the above code.

Error:

```
"Expected a list of items but got type \"Page\"."
```

How can I send the data to `is_valid` in this case?

Comment: Why do you need to validate the existing model objects?

Comment: Some existing data has to be validated as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Serializer classes accept a `Model` or `QuerySet` objects, `Page` object has a `object_list` attribute that contains a queryset of the model objects, therefore you need to pass `page.object_list`:

```
data = Model.objects.filter()
paginator = Paginator(data, 100)
page = paginator.page(int(page_number))
serializer = self.serializer_class(page.object_list, many=True)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Comment: Getting this error now:
`"Expected a list of items but got type \"QuerySet\"."`